# How to create cascading combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, cascadingdropdown

I am new to programming and I want to create a cascading Combobox for a project, but there seems to be a logic error that I can't seem to know how to fix.

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CSubject.SelectedIndexChanged

    Try
        If CSubject.SelectedItem = 0 Then
            CTask.Items.Clear()
            If Not (CTask.Items.Contains("Bonds")) And Not (CTask.Items.Contains("Timetables")) And Not (CTask.Items.Contains("Counting")) Then
                CTask.Items.Add("Bonds")
                CTask.Items.Add("Timetables")
                CTask.Items.Add("Counting")
            End If
        ElseIf CSubject.SelectedItem = 1 Then
            CTask.Items.Clear()
            If Not (CTask.Items.Contains("Phonics")) And Not (CTask.Items.Contains("Spelling")) And Not (CTask.Items.Contains("Reading")) Then
                CTask.Items.Add("Phonics")
                CTask.Items.Add("Spelling")
                CTask.Items.Add("Reading")
            End If
        ElseIf CSubject.SelectedItem = 2 Then
            CTask.Items.Clear()
            If Not (CTask.Items.Contains("Drawing")) And Not (CTask.Items.Contains("Tracing")) And Not (CTask.Items.Contains("Colouring")) Then
                CTask.Items.Add("Drawing")
                CTask.Items.Add("Tracing")
                CTask.Items.Add("Colouring")
            End If

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: How you know that there is an error? Please, remove `Try .. Catch` block from the code - this what hiding possible errors from you.

Comment: thanks but after removing try-catch and running it, it says: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll,  how do I fix this

Comment: It should said also a line number where error occurs. Please set `Option Strict` to `On` in the project or write on first line of the file to get compiler errors early

Comment: "If CSubject.SelectedItem = 0"  -- Did you possibly intend to use `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedItem`?  `SelectedItem` is an object that can be any type whereas `SelectedIndex` is an integer.

Comment: OMG Thank you everyone you just saved my life... it works now. I was supposed @TnTinMn was right, I should have used SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem.

Comment: @CaiusJard answer is probably the _right_ way to go about doing this.  Though, I can appreciate a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: With `Option Strict On` you wouldn't waste time by writing this question, instead you would get compiler error while you are writing that comparison code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Cascading as in you select a country from the "Country" combo box and the "City" combobox fills with cities only in that country?

I personally think the easiest way for this to use binding and create some custom tables:

- Add a new DataSet to your project
- Open it, right click the surface an choose Add New .. DataTable
- Right click it or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> and Add..Column
- Make it an integer, call it ID, right click it and set it as primary key
- Add another column called CountryName etc
- Add another datatable called City
- Add columns of CountryId (NOT a primary key) and CityName
- Click in the grey bar to the left of country Id so the row goes blue, then drag the blue row onto COuntryId in city and left go, confirm in the dialog that appears that parent is country.id and child is city.countryid

You now have this:

[image]

- Make a new form
- Show the data sources window (view menu, other windows option)
- Fully expand all the nodes in the datasources. Note that you have two City - one at the top level and one nested underneath
- Click the dropdown next to city/country name and change it from textbox to combobox

[image]

- Drag and drop the two ...name fields onto the form, country first. Do not drop the top level city, drag the city that is nested beneath the country
- We're actually going to undo some of what was done here, because the form designer doesn't bind things up in the right way for what we want, but what was done was mostly helpful
- In the Properties grid change the DropDownStyle of the combos to DropDownList
- Expand the DataBindings [+] and right click the text binding and choose reset (deletes it)
- Set the DataSource to Country/CityBindingSource depending on the combo (country combo → country bindingsource etc)
- Set the DisplayMember to Country/City name

Now we just need to add some data. Put this in the constructor code of the form (or the form load, or whatever)

```
        Dim r = someDataSet.Country.AddCountryRow(1, "USA")
        someDataSet.City.AddCityRow(r, "New York")
        someDataSet.City.AddCityRow(r, "Chicago")

        r = someDataSet.Country.AddCountryRow(2, "Canada")
        someDataSet.City.AddCityRow(r, "Toronto")
        someDataSet.City.AddCityRow(r, "Vancouver")
```

That's it; run the app - choose USA from the box and see your choices are NY or Chicago. Change it to Canada, and see the choices for city to revise to Toronto/Vancouver

If you want a complete sample project (no binaries, for obvious reasons; you have to build it yourself) that implements the steps above, download this picture and rename it to .zip:

[image]

It's C# (because that was what I had open at the time) but there is precious little code in it because most of the work is done visually/is the same in either language (and but for a single `var` that is `Dim` in vb and 6 semicolons, it's identical)

Comment: It looks like @LungileNgidi probably went with an alteration of their original code but I agree this is a better approach.  Quick fixes come back to haunt you in the long-run.

Comment: Like when the task becomes "load these 1000 lines of countries and cities from a file and make cascading combo boxes out of them".. all that hardcoded "if index = 1 then.." will end up in the trash at some point, I'm sure :)

Comment: Well, you'd _hope_ that's the case in the future.  Can't say I haven't band-aid fixed legacy apps the same way, though.

Comment: The sad part is, this way took me about 1.5 minutes to do (undoubtedly far less time than has been poured into the OP's way) even if it did take 10 times longer to write up.. But sometimes when people sweat over something for a long time, they become attached to the idea that it's good and tossing it out is anathema.. Sunk cost fallacy I'm assured it's called!

Comment: The goal is not how quick you can implement feature, but how easy somebody can maintain it. For example this approach can be down with few lines of code as well  without touching designer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your original question, because you would be able to resolve your issue by letting compiler to check types errors before running application.

You can simplify your code by using `Dictionary` as data structure for subjects and related tasks. Dictionary will have a key as name of the subject and value is a collection of related tasks.
With Dictionary you can get collection of tasks by given subject name `value = dictionary("key")` or use safer method `value = dictionary.GetValueOrDefault("key", "not found")`
When you see `if .. else` statement - consider to use a dictionary, especially when key and value relations are dynamic.

```
Option Strict On

Public Class ComboBoxForm
    Private ReadOnly _selections As Dictionary(Of String, String())

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        _selections = New Dictionary(Of String, String()) From
        {
            {"- not selected -", {"- not selected -"}},
            {"Math", {"- not selected -", "Bonds", "Timetables", "Counting"}},
            {"Language", {"- not selected -", "Phonics", "Spelling", "Reading"}},
            {"Art", {"- not selected -", "Drawing", "Tracing", "Colouring"}}
        }

        cbxSubjects.DataSource = _selections.Keys.ToArray()
        cbxTasks.DataSource = _selections.Values.First()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CbxTasks_SelectionCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxSubjects.SelectionChangeCommitted
        Dim subjects = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)

        Dim allowedTasks = _selections(subjects.SelectedValue)
        cbxTasks.DataSource = allowedTasks
    End Sub
End Class
```

Few things to note:

1. `Option Strict On` - very important, this enables type checks during compile time
2. Don't wrap your code with `Try .. Catch` block, thrown exceptions are best tool to find errors quicker.
3. Use `SelectionChangeCommitted` event to handle selections selected by user.

> Occurs when the **user changes** the selected item and that change is
> displayed in the ComboBox

4. Use `.DataSource` to set collection of values to the ComboBox, rather then adding them one by one.

Comment: @CaiusJard, in this example designer is used only to put comboboxes on the form. No need of "heavy" `DataTable` or `DataSet`, simple array will work as data source as well.